# How to increment top attribute of div in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need to increment the value top attribute of a div. for some reason it doesn't work.

i tried to use obj.style.top and increase the value but it doesn't work.

```js
let sqr = document.getElementById("sqr")
let val = parseInt(sqr.style.top)
sqr.style.top = (val + 100) + "px";
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

#sqr {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index2.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sqr"></div>
  <script src="index2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I just want the square move up about 100 px.
thanks.

Comment: `sqr.style.top` will only look at an inline style set on the HTML tag, not a value that is set in CSS

Comment: what im suppose to write instead?

Comment: `<div id = "sqr" style="top:100px"></div>`

Comment: what is the difference between this and define it in CSS file?

Comment: The difference is what I said, the JavaScript line `this.style` does not look at what is defined in the CSS file, only what is set on the element inline.

Comment: how can i change it in the css file and not define it as inline?

Comment: And dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9444751/383904

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
sqr.style.top= (sqr.offsetTop + 100) + "px";
```

style.top returns the top value set in style attribute on the html tag.

Comment: how can i do it with percents?

Comment: As in you want to add some percent of top instead of 100px ?

Answer (score 0):

The [`.style` DOM property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) returns a [CSS Style Declaration object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) containing **the styles that have been set on the object through the HTML `style` attribute**. Since your `div` doesn't have any inline styles applied to it, that technique won't return anything.

Instead, use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), which returns the computed value of any/all styles, regardless of how/where they were set (inline, JavaScript, stylesheet).

Also (FYI):

As a best practice, you should always specify the optional second argument for `parseInt()` ([the radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters)) to ensure you don't accidentally get a value you didn't expect.

```js
let sqr = document.getElementById("sqr")
let val = parseInt(getComputedStyle(sqr).top, 10);
sqr.style.top= (val + 100) + "px";
```

```css
body{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    position: relative;
}
#sqr{
    height: 30px;
    width:30px;
    background-color: blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "sqr"></div>
```