# Display value shoe false in console

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a div and button i click the button fist time no response and click again and show

```js
function banne() {
  var ban = document.getElementById("content");
  //consloe.log(ban.style.display === "none");
  if (ban.style.display === "none") {
    ban.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    ban.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.banner-content {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1b1b1b;
}
```

```html
<button class="banner" onclick="banne()"> know </button>
<div class="banner-content" id="content">
  Some Data
</div>
```

here the console value show false value but i write the style inline `style="display:none"` in div class **`banner-content`** it working, why the style sheet value not taken ,any idea?

Comment: See the answer of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444751/why-javascript-this-styleproperty-return-an-empty-string

Comment: Unable to answer. I will write a function here. Here's what you need - - - - -  function banne(){

var ban = document.getElementById("content");
if (window.getComputedStyle) {
    var spStyle = getComputedStyle(ban, '');
} else {
    var spStyle = ban.currentStyle;
}


 if (ban.style.display === "none") {
            ban.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            ban.style.display = "none";
        }
        
       console.log(spStyle.display);
    
}

Answer (score 2):

Javascript can't access the style mentioned in the CSS file with the `ban.style.display`. You have to use `getComputedStyle()` method.

```js
window.getComputedStyle(ban, null).getPropertyValue("display");
```

But in your case I think it is better use a class based toggle maybe like,

**CSS**

```css
.banner-content {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1b1b1b;
}
.banner-content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```js
function banne() {
  var ban = document.getElementById("content");
  ban.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

Comment: No, as the visibility is based on classes we can toggle the class using javascript and make it hidden/visible. No need to access the display value, atleast in this case.

Answer (score 0):

While `style` doesn't register the stylesheet properties, you can check if the style does *not* equal to "block" and then set it to block, otherwise none. Also see the difference between getComputedStyle and `style`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

```js
function banne() {
  var ban = document.getElementById("content");
  //consloe.log(ban.style.display === "none");
  if (ban.style.display !== "block") {
    ban.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    ban.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.banner-content {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1b1b1b;
}
```

```html
<button class="banner" onclick="banne()"> know </button>
<div class="banner-content" id="content">
  Some Data
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers.

Add a listener to the document. To toggle display, use a separate css class (`.visible` in the snippet) and toggle that. It makes your life so much easier.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", banne);

function banne(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains("banner")) {
    document.querySelector("#content").classList.toggle("visible");
  }
}
```

```css
.banner-content {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1b1b1b;
}

.banner-content.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="banner"> know </button>
<div class="banner-content" id="content">
  Some Data
</div>
```