# Javascript shows empty style property for document objects that I have styled using the css

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-events

I have a quick question. Would be glad if anyone can help me out with this one.

I am trying to create a navigation bar and then I have the following CSS code,

```
header .navbar .container .sliding-menu {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

In the above code, the `.sliding-menu` class given to a div that has content in it.

However when I use the Javascript and type the following code,

```
const slidingMenu = document.querySelector('header .navbar .container .sliding-menu');
console.log(slidingMenu.style.transform);
```

**console returns an empty string to me. Does anyone know the reason? Thanks.**

*Adittional Info:*

I will provide the whole code below if anyone wants it for reference.

HTML

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Computia | Computers & Related Accessories | Best Price in Sri Lanka</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="logo">Computia</h1>
                <div class="sliding-menu">
                    <h2>Navigate</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Journal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shopping Bag</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <h2>Account</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sign In / Register</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wishlist</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Returns</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Gift Certificates</a></li>
                        <select name="currency" id="currency">
                            <option value="LKR">LKR</option>
                            <option value="USD">USD</option>
                            <option value="AUD">GBP</option>
                        </select>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="hamburger">
                    <div class="line-1"></div>
                    <div class="line-2"></div>
                    <div class="line-3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
/* -------------------------- */
/* --------CSS Reset-------- */
/* ------------------------- */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* ----------------------------- */
/* --------Main Styling--------- */
/* ---------------------------- */

:root {
    --primary-color: #118ab2;
}

html, body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
}

a, p {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/* ------------------------------------ */
/* --------Reusable Components--------- */
/* ------------------------------------ */

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* ------------------------ */
/* ---------Navbar-------- */
/* ------------------------*/

header .navbar .container {
    position: relative;
}

header .navbar .container h1,
header .navbar .container .sliding-menu
{
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

header .navbar .container .hamburger {
    background-color: chartreuse;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

header .navbar .container .sliding-menu {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

header .navbar .container .hamburger div {
    height: 3px;
    margin: 4.5px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(201, 190, 190);
    border-radius: 100px;
}

/* Navbar-classLists */

/* .hamburger-toggled .line-1 {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hamburger-toggled .line-2 {
    opacity: 0
}

.hamburger-toggled .line-3 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
} */
```

Javascript

```
const slidingMenu = document.querySelector('header .navbar .container .sliding-menu');
console.log(slidingMenu.style.transform);
```

I tried for around three hours and could not find the issue. Please help if someone can. Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value translateX by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267189/how-to-get-value-translatex-by-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `element.style` returns the inline CSS style for the element, and not the computed style based on CSS stylesheets.

To get the computed style, use `window.getComputedStyle(element)`.

More information here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle
- [why javascript this.style[property] return an empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444751/why-javascript-this-styleproperty-return-an-empty-string)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now I understand it. What I actually want to do is change this set the translate(100%) back to translate(0) using javascript. I read the docs and it says that we cant do it with the computedStyle as computedStyle is read-only. So how do I actually change the property if it can not be accessed using element.style?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a certain style of an element, you should use getComputedStyle() method.

I recommend you to read how it works https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getcomputedstyle.asp

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now I understand it. What I actually want to do is change this set the translate(100%) back to translate(0) using javascript. I read the docs and it says that we cant do it with the computedStyle as computedStyle is read-only. So how do I actually change the property if it can not be accessed using element.style?

Comment: element.style will allow you to change it, but you can't log it on the console.